# decrypt IPA data like, app name, version, icon etc [MVC C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ipa, info.plist, diawi

**Updated Question**

I have managed to read the info.plist file and I got the below response. I don't know how to decrypt into XML.

[image: screenshot]

I am not sure, how can I read this?

---

**Actual Question**

I want to create an application like, [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com).

For that, I have completed the Android application upload part and now I want to read the IPA information like application name, application version, package name etc in C#.

I have searched a lot but could not found any documentation for that.

Can anyone please guide me the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

An IPA file is a ZIP file, so the first thing you need to do is extract this file.

After unzip IPA file, we will get a folder named `Payload`, and a file with extension `app` will be stored in folder `Payload`, 
maybe this app named is **xxxx.app**, and `info.plist` we can located in this app xxxx.app, the path related to folder Payload should be **Payload/xxxx.app/info.plist**.

```
    // parse info.plist
    File plistFile = new File(plistFilePath);
    NSDictionary rootDict = null;
    try {
        rootDict = (NSDictionary) PropertyListParser.parse(plistFile);

        // get bundle id
        NSString parameter = (NSString) rootDict.objectForKey("CFBundleIdentifier");
        ipaInfo.put("CFBundleIdentifier", parameter.toString());

        // get application name
        parameter = (NSString) rootDict.objectForKey("CFBundleName");
        ipaInfo.put("CFBundleName", parameter.toString());

        // get version
        parameter = (NSString) rootDict.objectForKey("CFBundleVersion");
        ipaInfo.put("CFBundleVersion", parameter.toString());

        // get bundle display name
        parameter = (NSString) rootDict.objectForKey("CFBundleDisplayName");
        ipaInfo.put("CFBundleDisplayName", parameter.toString());

        // get ios mini. version
        parameter = (NSString) rootDict.objectForKey("MinimumOSVersion");
        ipaInfo.put("MinimumOSVersion", parameter.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: NSDirectory is the class of Xcode and not of C#, may I know is there any library for the same in c#?

Comment: var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var row in File.ReadAllLines(PATH_TO_FILE))
  data.Add(row.Split('=')[0], string.Join("=",row.Split('=').Skip(1).ToArray()));
Console.WriteLine(data["ServerName"]);

Comment: I have updated the question. Actually, I can read the info.plist file but it is encrypted and the code you have shared is only able to read the XML file.